# What is the best way to do internationalization in an app with Angular 17?

Tags: angular, internationalization, documentation

I'm currently developing a new app with Angular 17 and I can't find any documentation about I18n in the new Angular.dev
I don't know if maybe I should use ngx-translate.

I didn't try anything yet, I've seen some blogs and posts but none of them about Angular 17.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mainstream options, including, but not limited to:

- Angular Internationalization [angular-i18n](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview)
- Transloco [transloco](https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/)
- ngx-translate [ngx-translate](http://www.ngx-translate.com/)
- i18n ally [i18n-ally](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=openscript.i18n-ally-fork)

I'd highly recommend using the first option, Angular Internationalization. It's simple to set up and use, there's heaps of documentation. Because it's built by the Angular team, you know it will be well maintained an updated into the future. It works well with Angular 17 too (I haven't tested the other option with Angular 17 yet)